# What is this weird group when importing an FBX, and how do I remove

Tags: groups

[image: wired group]

I imported this in as an FBX and all the objects seem to have this weird grouping. How do I remove it and how did I do this?

Comment: @RayMairlot I don't think it's a duplicate. That question is more about the visual representation of relationships and how that can be hidden, while this question is about how to remove the relationship itself.